# Using Proxy , Cookies not sent in angular 4 app using withCredentials set to true

Tags: ajax, angular, cookies, proxy, cors

I am host angular 4 app on my localhost , Since I need to make api request to my backend which is hosted on web (say  https://example.com ) I am using proxy . Here is my proxy config file.

```
  "*": {"target":"https://example.com",
"secure": false,
"logLevel": "debug",
"changeOrigin": true }
```

So that every request I make goes through the target url . When I make my first request to login page with credentials included I receive cookies in response.But then when I make another request ( POST ) to  https://example.com/images I am redirected to the login page . I can see in my network that there are no cookies being sent with the Request headers, however I did receive them from my first login request . I checked out many solutions to this problem. Many of them asked to include {withCredentials=true} in my ajax request which I did in every request.Here is my request

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "https://example.com/images",
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain:true,
            headers: {
               // includes necessary headers .
              },
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },

            data:data1 ,
            //data1 is json formatted


            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res)
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                console.log(status);
            }
        });
```

But this did not solve the problem. I suspect the cookies are getting lost due to proxy , or the browser is not handling them correctly. I checked I have allowed third party cookies . I need to send those session cookies with this second request . I tried to manually add them but I did not find a way to get and send them along with this request. how can I tackle this issue ? If I remove proxy then I will get the CORS issue . I do not have access to the backend server. hence I tried handling CORS using proxy which works correctly for login request. But this second request is not being sent with cookies. Anyone who can  help with this ?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in Angular 6 with proxy.  I've set withCredentials: true and still don't see the cookie getting passed.  I see two 307 redirects in the Chrome dev tools showing that the proxy is working and those calls have the cookie.  But the final call to the API does not have the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using jQuery in your angular app, and why use it to do ajax requests, if angular provides an [http client](https://angular.io/guide/http)?

You better use it and then, use [interceptors](https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-interceptors/) to add headers to the requests.

When using Angular, do it the Angular way. And use its tools/libraries/patterns.

Comment: Working on that , will get back with the update , thanks.

Comment: Issue still persists even after using http client , this was expected since  request still remains the same . I have used HttpHeaders to add headers with RequestOptions